# Issue with match.call

Tags: r

I wrote a function that uses `match.call`, and it works when I call the function directly, however, when the function is called within another function it breaks. I believe it has to do with how `match.call` handles environments, but I can't figure it out. Here is a reproducable example:

```
tester <- function() {

  var <- "helloworld"

  myFunc(var)

}


myFunc <- function(x) {

  tmp <- match.call()
  tmp[[1]] <- quote(toupper)
  eval(tmp)

}

tester() # error

myFunc("helloworld") # works fine
```

I believe that when `myFunc` is called within `tester` it can't find `var` because it exists in the isolated environment of the `tester` function.

Any ideas on how to get `myFunc` to work inside `tester` would be appreciated. I've tried changing the environment for `eval` and `match.call`, but to no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your suspicion is exactly right.

The very simple solution is to evaluate the function in its parent’s context: replace `eval` with `eval.parent`.

```
myFunc <- function(x) {
  tmp <- match.call()
  tmp[[1]] <- quote(toupper)
  eval.parent(tmp)
}
```

Generally, the function `traceback` can help tremendously with debugging similar issues:

```
> tester()
Error in as.character(x) :
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
```

Ok, but which “closure” (= function) are we talking about?

```
> traceback()
5: toupper(x = var)
4: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
3: eval(tmp) at #5
2: myFunc(var) at #5
1: tester()
```

The first line has the clue: `toupper(x = var)`. In the context of `tester`, `var` refers to the function (closure) `stats::var` which is found because its package is attached.

Comment: Oh, and changing the environment of `eval` works as well. In fact, that’s exactly what `eval.parent` does; it’s equivalent to `eval(tmp, envir = parent.frame())`. Don’t be misled by the fact that this is the default value of `eval`’s parameter `envir` anyway: specifying an argument value and using its default can produce different values because parameter defaults are evaluated *inside* the function whereas arguments you pass into a function are evaluated outside of it. This is super confusing.

Comment: Technically, it's equivalent to `eval(tmp,envir = parent.frame(2))`, which I swore I tried, but this seems to work so thanks

Comment: Ah, I see your comment