# Is there a way to make match.call + eval combination work when called from a function?

Tags: r, eval

I am using a package that has 2 functions which ultimately look like the following:

```r
pkgFun1 <- function(group) {
  call <- match.call()
  pkgFun2(call)
}

pkgFun2 <- function(call) {
  eval(call$group)
}
```

If I just call `pkgFun1(group = 2)`, it works fine. But I want to call it from a function:

```
myFun <- function(x) {
  pkgFun1(group = x)
}
myFun(x = 2)
## Error in eval(call$group) : object 'x' not found
```

Is there any way to avoid this error, if I can't modify the package functions, but only `myFun`?

There are similar questions, such as [Issue with match.call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40180848/issue-with-match-call) or [Non-standard evaluation in a user-defined function with lapply or with in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55813859/non-standard-evaluation-in-a-user-defined-function-with-lapply-or-with-in-r), but my particular issue is that I can't modify the part of code containing the `eval` call.

Comment: Did the posted solution solve your problem?  It's not perfect, but it might  be good enough.

Comment: yes, I guess it would work. But apparently my actual issue is more involved...anyway it has been solved by using another package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pkgFun2 that is wrong, so I think you're out of luck without some weird contortions. It needs to pass the appropriate environment to eval(); if you can't modify it, then you can't fix it.

This hack might appear to work, but in real life it doesn't:

```
pkgFun1 <- function(group) {
  call <- match.call()
  f <- pkgFun2
  environment(f) <- parent.frame()
  f(call)
}
```

With this, you're calling a copy of `pkgFun2` modified so its environment is appropriate to evaluate the call.  It works in the test case, but will cause you untold grief in the future, because *everything* that is not local in `pkgFun2` will be searched for in the wrong place.  For example,

```
myFun <- function(x) {
  eval <- function(...) print("Gotcha!")
  pkgFun1(group = x)
}
myFun(x = 2)
# [1] "Gotcha!"
```

Best is to fix `pkgFun2`.  Here's one fix:

```
pkgFun1 <- function(group) {
  call <- match.call()
  pkgFun2(call, parent.frame())
}

pkgFun2 <- function(call, envir) {
  eval(call$group, envir = envir)
}
```

**Edited to add:** Actually, there is another hack that is not so weird that should work with your original `pkgFun1` and `pkgFun2`.  If you force the evaluation of `x` to happen in `myFun` so that `pkgFun1` never sees the expression `x`, it should work.  For example,

```
myFun <- function(x) {
  do.call("pkgFun1", list(group = x))
}
```

If you do this, then after `myFun(2)`, the `pkgFun1` variable `call` will be `pkgFun1(group = 2)` and you won't get the error about `x`.

Comment: the first hack is not really relevant, as we assume that we can't modify pkgFun's...but thanks for the second idea